Is the word "though" a word that should be isolated with commas?
I read Starlight 6 text book for schoolers of the 6th grade. Why is the word "though" isolated with commas here? 
As I can see, this word does not introduce new sentence like here:
"Though I was lazy, I did all the homework."

There’s nothing wrong with

One day, though, he fell in love with a young girl ...

This one is fine too:

The hole, though, led down into the sea.

Though is an interruption here.  These are usually set off by a pair of bracketing commas.
We can remove such interruptions, and the sentence still works:

One day he fell in love with a young girl ...

This usage is different from that used as a subordinating conjunction, which cannot be removed:

Though I was lazy, I did all the homework.


In this particular case the commas are an important element in helping the reader to understand the meaning as he reads the narrative.
Though points back to and qualifies one day. The flow of the story is that Bolster lived a certain lifestyle as described in the first two sentences. But one day there was a change, which we read about in the rest of the story.
The commas are provided so that as we read we know to connect though with the preceding words. If there were no commas it would be possible to connect though forwards, and we would now be trying to read it as "though he fell in love with a young girl called Agnes and asked her to marry him." At this point we would realise we'd misread it, because there is no contrasting clause. (Something like Though he fell in love with her, he was too shy to tell her.) We would work out the correct meaning, but we'd do it by going back and reading the sentence again. The commas help us to get it right the first time.
